# How to mark an assembly as obsolete

Tags: c#, attributes, obsolete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to mark an assembly as deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475014/is-it-possible-to-mark-an-assembly-as-deprecated)

I have the need to mark an assembly as obsolete. I am aware of the [ObsoleteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx). The bad thing is, it cannot be used on assembly-level. So, I would have to mark all the members because the whole assembly should be replaced with another.

Is there any possibility to mark a complete assembly as obsolete, instead all members?

Comment: nope... you can use something like PostSharp to add a ObsoleAttribute to all your classes, interfaces, enums etc. without cluttering the code itself. http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475014/is-it-possible-to-mark-an-assembly-as-deprecated

Comment: +1 on @dboarman: voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Eric Lipper's answer: [Is it possible to mark an assembly as deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475014/is-it-possible-to-mark-an-assembly-as-deprecated/4475247#4475247)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I haven't found this question. I've probably used the wrong search terms.