# How to mark entire dll or csproj as obsolete

Tags: c#, dll, csproj

I have a couple projects in my solution that need to be marked as obsolete. Is there an easy way to mark the csproj or dll files, or do I have to suck it up and mark each class with the obsolete tag?  There's hundreds of files so any more efficient solution is greatly appreciated.

I tried using the [Obsolete] tag for each individual class, but there's a lot of files so this would take a lot of time.

Comment: [`ObsoleteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=net-8.0) doesn't have the [`AttributeTargets.Assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributetargets?view=net-8.0) target, so I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4475247/982149 ?

Comment: @Fildor Not exactly; the functionality was split up into several projects. I don't know if I can use that tag to point to different assemblies.

Comment: Re: "there's hundreds of files", you can use the *Replace in files* functionality in VS (or your IDE of choice) and just replace all `public ` with `[Obsolete] public ` (you may need to get a little fancy with Regex in the search, to prevent it from catching variables named `republic ` etc).

Comment: @NPras that's what I'm going to end up doing. Thanks for the suggestion